# How can I populate listboxes via combobox on Access Form?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I need to Populate several listboxes with values from a table. I would like to populate a combobox with the values from the first column of that table. Then I want to fill in the textboxes with the rest of the values of that record.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can do this with binding but I need to edit the textboxes and overwrite the underlying table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code that might help you out. It'll also work for list boxes! Let me know if you need any more help

```
comboName.RowSource = "Select * from targetTable where primaryKey like '*" & searchCriteriaTextbox & "*';"
comboName.Value = comboName.ItemData(1)
```